# how do you get seconds to start on page load using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clock

I have gotten this far by stripping down some other code;
I'm thinking it as something to do with `currentTimeString`?
i need the second timer clock to start at 0 on page load instead of just showing the clock time.

```
var d = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000 ?>);

function updateClock() {
  // Increment the date
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000);

  var currentSeconds = d.getSeconds();

  // Generate the display string
  var currentTimeString = currentSeconds + " " + "Seconds ";

  // Update the time
  document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}

window.onload = function() {
  updateClock();
  setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
}
```

Comment: This will display the amount of seconds into the minute set on the system clock, i.e. 0-59. Is that what you're trying to do or no? If not, please elaborate what you're trying to do by [edit]ing the question.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you just want to display seconds 0-59, if so then try updating just seconds each time and use `firstChild.innerHTML` intead of `nodeValue`

```
d.getSeconds(d.getSeconds() + 1);

  var currentSeconds = d.getSeconds();

  // Generate the display string
  var currentTimeString = currentSeconds + " " + "Seconds ";

  // Update the time
  document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.innerHTML = currentTimeString;
```